# How can I improve the rendering of d3 logscale for my data so it doesn't show those 'm' characters?

Tags: d3.js

[image]

Here is a snippet of my code:

`settings.unit == 'log' ? (axisScale = scaleLog().domain([self.data.min === 0 ? 0.001:self.data.min, self.data.max]).range(isH ?[0, settings.svgw] : [settings.svgw, 0])).clamp(true) : (axisScale = scaleLinear().domain([self.data.min, self.data.max]).range(isH ? [0, settings.svgw] : [settings.svgw, 0]))`